# What is the oldest common English word?

Tags: etymology

I'm trying to formalize [What is the oldest still-in-use English word?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35259/what-is-the-oldest-still-in-use-english-word) which was closed as vague.

Consider the "age" of a word to be the length of time since it was first used with the (more-or-less) the current meaning and pronunciation.

Obviously, there are lots of words date from Classical Antiquity: *Coitus*, *agenda*, and *terminus* are among thousands of words that would mean the same to Julius Caesar as they do to us.
[Assignment for the under-worked: write a logical, grammatical English sentence consisting entirely of such words; extra credit if it also makes sense *in Latin*.]

There are even words preserved untouched from ancient Greece (*echo*, *academe*, *halcyon*, *stasis*).

Are there any word that pre-dates those, such as some word that a Mycenaean potter or a Hittite horseman would say that, I don't know, Matt Lauer would understand perfectly?

My guess is *ma*, meaning mother, but I have no proof.

Comment: If you're happy to accept "ma" as a "word", it's probably fair to say it's the oldest word in many languages, and very likely predates anything that we'd really call language in the first place. It's an easy first articulation for babies, and I believe it (or something very similar) occurs in many if not most languages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  -- I don't know if I would be "happy".  What would really make me happy would be a peer-reviewed paper proving that some *Homo habilis* in Olduvai Gorge crushed the skull of a rival with a rock then climbed atop a termite mound, held the bloody weapon to the sky, and croaked "Monarchy!" but I'm not really expecting that to happen.  A man can dream, though.

Comment: Over thousands of years it's rather unlikely that many words could continue to mean the same thing, if for no other reason than that hardly any concepts (referents) would still "mean" the same thing in the minds of men. But I think "Ma" (as the baby/child's term for it's mother) is one of the select few to qualify on that score.

Comment: About "extra credit if it also makes sense in Latin": It can't!
I'm not an expert on Old English, but still, English is a Germanic language. The oldest sentences in English will sound exactly like Old Fresian.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That is not entirely true: a great many of our roots can be traced back up to Prehistoric times. But will Malvolio accept a word that was pronounced somewhat differently, or had different inflectional properties?

Comment: It appears that I can't edit a comment twice. I meant to add link to [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OeC1yAaWG34) where a guy speaking Old English tries to buy a cow from a farmer who speaks Fresian.

See how much of it you can understand. Perhaps that will answer your question.

Comment: @prashnrao: There's a time limit (4-5 minutes, I think) on how long a comment remains "editable".

Comment: @Cerberus: I didn't say *no* words can be traced to very early forms. Simply that even of those which can, many will have different meanings/connotations now because the entire world in which we live today has changed so much over millennia.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks! I'm still not used to the system here.

Comment: A Latin sentence that would make sense in (headline) English isn't very hard, not even if it must be a full clause: *gymnasia credit analysis*, or *Museum vacuum adit* (British plural). It gets difficult if the sentence has to mean the same thing in both languages...

Comment: @FumbleFingers: That is true, but there are a great many roots with meanings that have remained fairly close to their Proto-Germanic ancestors, far closer than the various meanings of *set* in Modern English are to each other.

Comment: You want the same pronunciation? That’s not reasonable. We don’t know for sure how things used to be said. And you discount most words of Modern English because of the Great Vowel Shift. Seems like an unreasonable question.

Comment: Please define 'age of a word'. I think it is not possible to do so coherently. Must it be written? Then is the age of the word the age of the oldest manuscript in which it appears? Also, define English or are you counting words that came from Latin (before 1066)? or proto-Germanic/proto IE? I think the problem is 'attestable' since 'the' may very well be 'older' than 'one', it's just that 'one' has more cognates in other IE languages.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One candidate would be the Hittite word for "water", which was "watar" or "wadar" (there are different views on exactly what the consonant was).

Comment: We may have a winner.  Most people say "watar" or "wadar" *today*.  I'll give it a day if someone comes up with anything older.  **Utterly irrelevant sidenote** : the word [otter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otter) comes from the same root as water.

Comment: I'm calling it: water it is.

Comment: Note that Hittite was Indo-European, as is English. So while English "water" is not *descended* from the Hittite word, they likely both came from the same source.

Comment: How old are Hittite words?

Comment: @Andrew: Wikipedia: "The language is attested in cuneiform, in records from the 16th (Anitta text) down to the 13th century BC, with isolated Hittite loanwords and numerous personal
names appearing in an Old Assyrian context from as early as the 20th century BC." Not to be confused with [Hitite Microwave](http://www.hittite.com/company/), founded in 1985: "designs and develops high performance integrated circuits (ICs), modules, subsystems and instrumentation"

Answer (score 4):

According to a [press release from Reading University](http://www.reading.ac.uk/about/newsandevents/releases/PR19825.aspx), "I", "we", "one", "two" and "three" are among the oldest.

Based on computer models of Indo-European language evolution, they estimate these words to be at least 10,000 years old and possibly as much as 30,000 years.

Comment: If I understand the press release correctly, "I", "we", "one", "two" and "three" *in the local language* were among the oldest words -- but not the English words!  "One" and "two" a barely older than Chaucer in their current form (and were "on" and "twa" before that).

Comment: @Malvolio If I understand the press release correctly, together with [this article](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/7911645.stm), these are the words that have changed the least from Proto-Indo-European to today. They mention 'water' as well, but say that the numerals appear to be the most change resistant of them all.

Comment: A thousand years ago, "I" was "ik"; "one" was "on"; "two" was "twa".  ("We" and "three" have been stable, for whatever reason.)  I'm pretty sure the BBC was misunderstand the actual paper.

Comment: @Malvolio: I don't think it's the BBC: I think the University of Reading's press release is garbled. Words *change* as language changes. I think the paper must be talking about *replacement*, from whatever source. The given words can all be traced back to IE roots, so they have not been replaced.

Comment: @Colin Fine -- That seems like silly too.  *All* words come from other words.  "Blog" comes from PIE (from `web*` meaning "weave", then OE `webb`, then `spider web`, when `web log`, finally `blog`.  Hardly makes "blog" an old word.

Answer (score 3):

Linguistically, that's really not a very good question. A word is not a concrete term, but rather a generalization made by speakers (and not linguists) to distinguish speech units on a pretty shady basis, the most solid of which is actually the writing system (i.e. "a word is what comes between two spaces"), thus, the phrase "cannot" will constitute one word, and the phrase "can not" two. Attempts to use a different basis will most likely drag you into the grey areas of the language, which linguists have a hard time with, such as determining what makes a 'set phrase', and whether it should count as one word or two.

That's not all — other than the elusiveness of the term *word* in the current language state (synchronous application), there's also the issue of language change over time and between dialects, not less elusive: there's no real way to compare words in ancient Greek or Hebrew to one another or to English words and say 'these are the same words'.

Someone above suggested a rather plausible test of recognition, however it probably still wouldn't do for a scientific test. A few reasons are:

1. There's no real telling how the words sounded in the ancient languages.
2. It's often hard to trace the route of a word between distant languages (e.g. if English got it from Greek, from Proto Indo-European, from Latin, etc.).
3. Even if we did know the old pronunciations, it would almost never be exactly the same, and often less resembling than it seems in the first place. Mind that aside from the consonants and the vowels there are also differences in stress and intonation.

So, although from many aspects it is quite plausible to compare language to a biological system in terms of evolution, it's still not possible to determine 'the oldest word in a language'. A word is new every time it is uttered, and a language changes every day — we can call it by any name we please, but English today is not the same English as yesterday.

Comment: This is a seriously silly question. Suppose, today, we all decided to borrow the PIE word _*wopsa_ 'wasp', and used it, it would become the oldest word in the world, right? Even though it's been dead for 4000 years? _The oldest man_ in the world has to exist, because everybody dies. However, there is no concept of "life" or "death" for words that is not just a metaphor, so there is no way to say what age a word has. If you count pronunciation, then any English word with a long vowel would be out of the running, because all the long vowels changed during the GVS, for instance.

Comment: I think you're falling victim to sorites.  Just because there are ambiguous cases does not mean a question is unanswerable.  An argument about whether *can not* is a single word doesn't make it difficult to say that *kangaroo* is a single word, while *Our Father who art in Heaven* is not.  As for the difficulty of pronunciation (both knowing an early pronunciation and deciding whether it qualifies as "the same"), I'm willing to treat that subjectively; I think *wadder* is sufficiently close to *water* that it's the current front runner. [continued]

Comment: As for etymology, it's not part of the question. If an  Hittite pronounced his word for *kidney* as /ˈkɪdni/ by complete coincidence, I'm still counting it.  And @JohnLawler, does it help that it was a *deliberately* silly question?

Answer (score 2):

I think your question needs a bit more work to make it answerable. I'll discuss the difficulties briefly:

Does a word like *pharaoh* count? The *OED* gives the etymology "post-classical Latin *Pharaon-*, *Pharao* (Vulgate) < Hellenistic Greek Φαραώ (Septuagint) < Hebrew *parʿōh* < Egyptian *pr-ʿo* great house" so it must be three thousand years old at least. But many words have etymological ancestors of similar antiquity, for example *white* is from the Indo-European root **kwidnos*, **kwitnos* and is likely at least as old. So what counts as a "still-in-use English word?"

Although it's very plausible that *ma* is ancient (see Larry Trask, [Where do *mama/papa* words come from?](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/linguistics/documents/where_do_mama2.pdf)), the *OED*'s first citation for the word in English is from 1823 ("E. Moor *Suffolk Words* at *Pa*, It is sometimes rather comic to hear a great chuckle-headed lout—*paa*-ing his father—or *maa*-ing his mother.") Searching for antedatings is hard because of the many false positives (for example *MA* meaning "Master of Arts"). So if you find an antedating, be sure to submit it to the *OED*!

Comment: Why wouldn't `pharaoh` count?  At least, I'll certainly count it back as far as Φαραώ -- פרעה (parʿōh) is clearly a, ahem, voiceless bilabial plosive and not voiceless labiodental fricative (a /p/ instead of an /f/).  Now I'm thinking `Torah`, which I wouldn't regard a *great* answer (because it's a proper noun not any residual resentment from Hebrew School), but the book and the name are some 3300 years old.

Comment: `White` by contrast *wouldn't* count.  You go up to the average English speaker, hold up a picture of King Tut and say "Φαραώ", he'll say, "Yeah, a pharaoh." Hold up a blank sheet of paper and say "*Kwidnos", he'd think you're insane.  And for all I know, he'd be right...

Comment: So your criteria include *the word must be recognizable to an average modern English speaker*? You should add that to the question.

Comment: How would you measure "recognizable" though? In his question Malvolio mentions "words preserved untouched from ancient Greece" and goes on to mention... *echo*. I've never been to Ancient Greece, but I don't think they pronounced ηχώ as [ˈekəʊ].

Comment: @Gareth Rees -- my example was Matt Lauer, an exceptionally unexceptional American TV "personality", but TWIAVP, so substitute whomever you want.  I was just trying to get at the idea of the modern English vocabulary.

Comment: @RegDwight -- I've never even been to modern Greece and in fact, I think it's fair to say my point of nearest approach would be the local gyro stand, so I'll have to ask: how *would* you (or, say, Demosthenes) pronounce ηχώ?

Comment: @Malvolio: the χ is probably a [x], the ω is most certainly not an [əʊ], and in fact I see an accent on the second syllable. But that is beside my actual point. After all, what one person might not recognize as the same word, another one might. And *that* is the actual point. How do you measure "recognizable"? Is it enough if 51 people out of 100 succeed? 49? 20? And what if native speakers of English recognize it as the same word, but native speakers of Greek do not? (A rather typical situation, I might add.) We need a clear set of bulletproof criteria, otherwise it's all just speculation.

Comment: @RegDwight -- it's speculation?  *All* speculation! Are you sure?  Oh my God!  Someone on the Internet is making an unsupported assertion!  Quick, Robin, to the Bat-Copter!  While there's still time!  Awaaaayyyy!

Answer (score 1):

Argh, as in an expression of, well, anything, but usually distaste. Around since the caveman times.
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/argh

Answer (score 1):

The word **lox** hasn’t changed in sound or meaning in 8,000 years according to Gregory Guy (a professor of linguistics at New York University) and a research on tracing word pronunciations. It is also said that the word *lox* was one of the clues that eventually led linguists to discover who the Proto-Indo-Europeans were, and where they lived.

> “The pronunciation in the Proto-Indo-European was probably ‘lox,’ and that’s exactly how it is pronounced in modern English,” he says. “Then, it meant salmon, and now it specifically means ‘smoked salmon.’ It’s really cool that that word hasn’t changed its pronunciation at all in 8,000 years and still refers to a particular fish.”
>
> In several thousand years, most words change beyond recognition, like the word *wheel*, which initially might have sounded “kʷékʷlos.” But there were some remarkable exceptions—like the timeless *lox*.
>
> “What is interesting about the word *lox* is that it simply happened to consist of sounds that didn’t undergo changes in English and several other daughter languages descended from Proto-Indo-European,” says Guy.
>
> <sub>http://nautil.us/blog/the-english-word-that-hasnt-changed-in-sound-or-meaning-in-8000-years</sub>

The etymology of *lox* from *[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lox)*:

> From Yiddish לאַקס‎ (*laks*, “salmon”), from Old High German *lahs*, from Proto-Germanic **lahsaz* (“salmon”), from Proto-Indo-European **laḱs-* (“salmon, trout”). Cognate to Icelandic *lax*, German *Lachs*. More at *lax*.

*[Water](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/water)* (as Colin answered before) is really good also as its Proto-Indo-European origin is **wódr̥*. [*Fire*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fire) is almost there but the origin Proto-Indo-European **péh<sub>₂</sub>wr̥* and Hittite  (*paḫḫur*) sounds more like between fire and its cognate pyre.

Here is a related excerpt from the book "Word Histories and Mysteries: From Abracadabra to Zeus (edited by Editors of the American Heritage Dictionaries):

[image]

Comment: One would imagine that **water** came before **lox** - first you find the water...

Comment: @Greybeard: Possibly, the word for their main food source was earlier and "lox" might have been used as food/fish. This was mentioned in another linguistics book. (Even though, based on the region they live, it was a specific type of fish). In some other languages, the cognate word for "lox" meant fish also. And, it looks like "lox" has the least change in sound trajectories or even spelling.

Comment: If interjections are allowed, then "Uh" is pretty primaeval.

Comment: @Greybeard: I believe it is impossible to trace back the interjections. PIE doesn't have a written record but there are linguistic reconstruction methods. However, I've read an article about the link between ancient cave drawings and early human languages.

Answer (score -1):

I believe cannabis is up there on the list as well. It originates from from the Greek word Kánnabis (κάνναβις), which comes from the Hebrew word קְנֵה בֹּשֶׂם [qěnēh bośem. Then later shortened to קַנַּבּוֹס (qannabbôs)], which means "sweet/aromatic cane". It is mentioned in the Old Testament 5 times and is in recipe an anointing oil recipe.

This is also where the word hemp gets it origins, as it comes from the word hanep, which is a latinization of the Germanic word kænep, which originates from kaneh bosm. It is believed that the Hebrew word originated from the Sumerian word kunibu or qunibu; which, if correct, would make it the oldest word still in use today, circa 20,000 BCE.

Comment: Unfortunately this answer seems partisan and a misunderstanding. If the origin of the word is Sumerian word kunibu or qunibu and the Hebrew is qěnēh bośem, then the word has changed over the years, and can be traced back in its present form only to the Greek - English is littered with words of Greek origin.